# How to center a letter on a face, with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

How can I center a letter on a face, with *Geometry Nodes*? As shown on the picture, I like to place randomly a collection of letters on a mesh object - f.e. on a icosphere. Everything is fine and works but the letters are not 100% centered.

I don't find my mistake - is there anyone with a idea what could cause this? Happy about all help

[image]

Comment: Please share your blend-file on https://blend-exchange.com/ . This will make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To instantiate letters in the center of faces of another mesh, you can use the following setup:

[image]

Since the node `String to Curves` outputs single instances, you have the possibility to move their position to their center right at the beginning before instantiation.

You can do this by subtracting the position of the individual letters from their *Pivot Point*.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Hi there, thx so much for this quick solution 

Comment: You are welcome! If this answer satisfactorily answered your question, consider marking it as *"Accepted Answer"* so that the question will show as solved. https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: ...as an addition to my question (if it´s ok to link s.th.?) the result i could realize with your help and answer: https://skfb.ly/oJ9RW

Comment: @smice Beautiful. It always pleases me to see what others then make of the answers! Many thanks for it!