# How to place letters without rotation on the faces of a torus with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

In addition to my last question, I have another question on the same topic. As you can see at the screenshot, the letters are clean and straight on the surfaces of the cube. The letters on the Torus do this too, but unfortunately the letters rotate around their own axis. How can you prevent this rotation with geometry nodes?

[image]

Link to my first question with the related blend file
[Question Part 1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/296894/how-to-center-a-letter-on-a-face-with-geometry-nodes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This has been answered before, so may get wiped as a duplicate if someone can find  a close-enough match .. but here goes, to make sure you get a timely response.)

To fully define an orientation, some kind of two-step alignment is needed. One to establish an axis, and another to spin around it.

If, for example, you wanted Object-Z to be your 'up' vector, this would do it for you:

[image]

Comment: I knew that the second "Align Euler" is the right way but i didn´t check the Pivot Field. Thanks so much 